# moving location of items in an array

Tags: python, arrays

[image: Question]
[image: Question]
How can I do this using python (no use of import)

The main problem I have is getting the items to loop around from the end of the array to the beginning of the array. I know this is fairly basic but then again I am a pretty basic programmer and this is harder than anything I have done.

Comment: No home work questions. what have you tried? show your code

Comment: [Please don't ask others to do your homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a function which shifts the players by one, then repeatedly call that function in a loop by `n` number of times.

for that function you can use unpacking:

```py
def move_to_right_by_one(lst: list) -> list:
    *rest, last = lst
    return [last, *rest]
```

It shifts the names by one. Now here is the full code:

```py
def move_to_right_by_one(lst: list) -> list:
    *rest, last = lst
    return [last, *rest]


def move_to_right(lst: list, n: int) -> list:
    for _ in range(n):
        lst = move_to_right_by_one(lst)
    return lst


player_name = ["Helen", "Adam", "Lidia", "Kwaru", "Priya", "Chan"]
n = 2
print(move_to_right(player_name, 2))
```

output:

```
['Priya', 'Chan', 'Helen', 'Adam', 'Lidia', 'Kwaru']
```

Remember that this is simple but not efficient for large number of `n`. Because after some shiftings the names come back to their original position, you can detect it (by calculating the remainder) and only shift the list for necessary number of times. Also currently we're copying the names in order to create the desired shifted list, this can be achieved more efficiently if you have a circular linked list.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a more simple way? I have a fairly basic knowledge of functions

Comment: @JoeHeap I think it's pretty simple, if you didn't learn functions yet, you can write the code right inside the for loop without calling any function.